# Are ProtoBuf attribute ProtoMember inherited with tag value in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

How does `.Net` `ProtoBuf` 's `ProtoMember` work in the inheritance chain? For example, look at the following classes.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract] //required?
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [ProtoMember(3)] //can tag value be 1 ?
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Questions are mentioned in the code inline.

(1) Do I need to mark the derived class `ProtoContract` if base class is already `ProtoContract`?
(2) For properties of derived class, can I reuse tag values (`int`) of `ProtoMember` already used in base class properties?

Answer (score 3):

(1) Do I need to mark the derived class ProtoContract if base class is already ProtoContract?
Yes, but You also should set order to deriver type

(2) For properties of derived class, can I reuse tag values (int) of ProtoMember already used in base class properties? yes, You can start from 1 in derived class

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you please elaborate a bit on this? *"Yes, but You also should set order to deriver type"* ?

Comment: sure, You should add attribute `[ProtoInclude(intOrder, typeof(DerivedClass))]` to base type; or use static class `RuntimeTypeModel` for another way mapping